# How to move lines between patterns to the end of a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to move several lines to the end of the file.

Example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6 blkn XYZ indf
7
8
9
10
11 lnkn ABCYDF knnfd
12
13
14
15
```

I want to move lines 6 to 11 to the end of the file. The patterns are `XYZ` for the beginning line and `ABC*` for the last line.

I managed already to copy them via `awk '/XYZ/,/ABC*/ {print}' file >> file` to the end of the file.

I don't know how to move these lines to the end, maybe some of you have an elegant solution for this.

Comment: Closely related: [Move first N lines of output to end without using temporary file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277756)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close already. Just save the lines in some variable and use an `END` rule to print it:

```
/XYZ/, /ABC.*/ { result = result $0 RS; next }
{print}
END { print result }
```